# Отправка данных в теле POST-запроса при аутентификацией?

Tags: post, oauth

Здравствуйте! Я разбираюсь с аутентификацией с помощью протокола OAuth. Моя задача - отправить POST-запрос на сервер, передав некоторые данные. С пустым POST-запросом (без передаваемых данных в теле) я разобрался. Подпись на сервер приходит правильная. Сервер мне сообщает только то, что не я не отправил никакие данные. В связи с этим, у меня возникло два взаимосвязанных вопроса. Поясните мне, пожалуйста, нужно ли добавлять эти данные, которые нужно отправить в теле запроса, в base string для дальнейшей генерации oauth_signature? И собственно говоря в каком виде эти данные после заголовка в запросе я должен буду отправить на сервер? Пример данных которые должен передать на сервер:

```
 category:1
 title:Енисей
 description:Краткое описание
 message:Полное описание
 other1:Омск
 other2:ул. Пролетарская, 22
 other3:54.9782695,73.3381964
 other4:88002000600
 other5:direktor@zarplaty.net
```

P. s под вторым вопросом я и имел ввиду не какие данные мне нужно отправить, а то как правильно я должен их сформировать в теле запроса (название 1:значение 1 или название 1=значение 1)? И какие между этими данными должны стоять знаки (запятая или &)? В самой документации к API не показан окончательные вид тела запроса. Я знаю только, что это должен быть не json, а простой ассоциативный массив (показан в примере в документации на php). Но я пишу приложение на другом языке. Благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

варианта два либо сериализовать данные, например так:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: "category=1&title=Енисей"
});
```

либо из данных сформировать массив (т.е объект в js)и отправить его на сервер где вы можете принять их примерно так :

```
 var data = [ тут ваши данные в виде ассоцитивного массива];
 $.ajax({
   url: "page.php",
   processData: false,
   data: data
 });
```

или по кусочкам :

```
$.ajax({
  url: "page.php",
  processData: false,
  data: {category:1,title:'Енисей'/*... и тд*/}
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Меня интересовал исключительно сырой вид представления тела POST-запроса. Не реализация в java script, так как приложение будет написано на java. Сейчас я пытаюсь пройти аутентификацию с помощью приложения для браузера, где весь POST-запрос необходимо составить самому без привлечения языков программирования.

Comment: я честно не очень понимаю как вы хотите составить POST без какого либо языка программирования...

Comment: параметры oauth_nonce и oauth_signature я конечно же составляю с помощью языка программирования (на java), а вот весь запрос делаю с помощью приложения Google Chrome Advanced Rest Client, где сам тип запроса составляется в ручную без программирования. Использую эту утилиту что бы понять какие данные в дальнейшем нужно отправить на сервер.